# Identify files that would be deleted when removing an rsync --link-dest directory?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, hardlink

I have a Time Machine-style backup system set up on my NAS (running BusyBox v1.16.1), using `rsync --link-dest` as described here: http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html

Is there an easy way to find out which files will be deleted if I delete an old backup directory, and which will just be unlinked? I assume one way would be to find which inodes in the old directory have only one link to them, but I don't know a way to do that. `rm --dry-run` anyone?

Bonus Points: Find a way to do the above, and also calculate the total disk space freed if the old backup is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to just use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) with the `-links` option.

Specifically you would want to do something like `find path -type f -links 1`.

I haven't tested, but I believe a command like this would delete all the multi-linked files.

```
# you might not need to escape the !, depends on your shell
# should find all the files that do NOT have a link count of 1 and delete them
find path -type f \! links 1 -print -delete
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. I don't need the second part; since the backup images are full of hard links, I just need to delete the oldest  backup directory.  
  
`find oldest/ -type f -links 1 >> files-lost-forever.txt;  
find oldest/ -type f -links 1 -print0 | xargs -0 du | awk '{total = total + $1}END{print total " bytes freed"}';  
rm -rf oldest;`

Comment: er... `s/du/du -k/` and `s/bytes/Kb/`