# RSync move files to a different directory if they were deleted on the server

Tags: linux, rsync

So right now I use rsync to synchronize files with a server. Sometimes the files on the server are deleted (I know about the `--delete` option and I do not use it) and those files are left in my local directory for me to clean up later.

Unfortunately this requires me to pull up the list of files on the server, figure out which files are no longer on the server, and move them to a different local directory.

I want to somehow automate this process. I do not know if such an option exists in rsync, but I would settle for anything as long as it would get automate this repetitive task.

Does anyone know how this could be accomplished?

Comment: I think you would have to write a custom script to move deleted files to the trash.

Comment: I actually don't wanna move my files to the trash, although I figure that's a minor change. In any case I figured out a solution which I'm about to post.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out on my own. The solution is to mount the SFTP directory from the server to a local directory using `sshfs` and then use `diff`. For those who wish to use this workaround you can find directions here: http://blog.damontimm.com/how-to-mount-a-sftp-folder-ssh-ftp-on-ubuntu-linux-using-sshfs-fuse/ and here: http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/05/compare-directories-using-diff-in-linux.html Just remember to use the `-o allow_other` option with sshfs otherwise you're going to have file permission problems.

Comment: I'd grown used to this for local backups with Carbon Copy Cloner on Mac OS X, which previously used an rsync variant called psync, but they went commercial, abandoned it, and lost that functionality.  lol

Comment: Isn't the "right way" to do this with `--link-dest`?  I've never used it myself, and you must seemingly write a script to make up a new directory each time, but it'll do the trick.  Appears less user-friendly than time machine : https://superuser.com/questions/441522/identify-files-that-would-be-deleted-when-removing-an-rsync-link-dest-director?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I've found a possible solution, but you have to run rsync two times.

In the first run, copy new and changed files, like:

```
rsync -xav source/ dest/
```

In the second run, delete and move files:

```
rsync --delete --backup --backup-dir=DIR_DELETED_FILES -xav source/ dest/
```

Note that --backup-dir can be absolute.